# Using make for multiple indexed jobs

Tags: makefile

I want to perform multiple jobs in a makefile, all jobs have a similar pattern:

```
all: job1 job2 job3 ... job21

job1: begin.x mid1.x end.x
    cat $^ > $@

job2: begin.x mid2.x end.x
    cat $^ > $@

...
job21: begin.x mid21.x end.x
    cat $^ > $@

mid1.x:
    echo "file 1" > $@
...
mid21.x:
    echo "file 21" > $@
```

Is there any way I can use an array as index for defining the jobs and its dependencies.

In the case where there are no dependencies, I can do something like:

```
n = 1 2 3 4 ... 21

all: $(n)

$(n):
    echo "file $@" > mid$@.x
```

but I haven't figure out how to do it when dependencies are involved.

Comment: This is what pattern and static pattern rules are for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what pattern/implicit rules [10 Implicit Rules](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Implicit-Rules) and [4.12 Static Pattern Rules](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Static-Pattern) are for.

Using implicit rules:

```
all: job1 job2 job3 ... job21

job%: begin.x mid%.x end.x
        cat $^ > $@

mid%.x:
        echo 'file $*' > $@
```

Using static pattern rules:

```
n = 1 2 3 ... 21
JOBS := $(addprefix job,$n)
MIDS := $(patsubst %,mid%.x,$n)

all: $(JOBS)

$(JOBS) : job% : begin.x mid%.x end.x
        cat $^ > $@

$(MIDS) : mid%.x :
        echo 'file $*' > $@
```

For the static pattern version if you want make to automatically clean up the `mid*.x` files the way it will for the pattern/implicit version you will need to add `.INTERMEDIATE: $(MIDS)` to the makefile as well.